# What is the Pythonic way to map a sequence of one custom class to another?

Tags: python, type-conversion

(...or, alternatively, what is the Pythonic version of C#'s `Select(...)` method? )

Given a list `l` of a custom class `A` what is the (most?) Pythonic way to map each element of `l` to a different custom class `B`?

for example, the following code will do it, but is it the most Pythonic way of doing it? Note, the real types have many properties.

```
l = [A('Greg', 33), A('John', 39)]

def map_to_type_b(the_list):
    new_list = []
    for item in the_list:
        new_list.append(B(item.name, item.age))

    return new_list

l2 = map_to_type_b(l)
```

I'm coming from a C# background, where I would use LinQ `select` or the `Select()` extensions method to project from the source sequence to a new sequence of type `B`.

Comment: Could you define a `from_A` class method on `B`? Then it's just `l2 = map(B.from_A, l)`, or `[B.from_A(inst) for inst in l]`. If `A` is a mapping, you could even do something clever like `[B(**inst) for inst in l]`.

Comment: Probably a list comprehension: `[B(a.name, a.age) for a in list_of_a]`

Comment: Note that I've removed references to *"complex type"*, as I'm probably not alone in immediately thinking of e.g. `1+2j`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I like your `from_A` idea as opposed to listing all the arguments to the constructor in the list comprehension its self. A question though, is that *Pythonic*, can you point me to any documentation or articles arguing for or against?

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you post your comments as answers so I might vote or accept them.

Comment: @PauloScardine can you post your comments as answers so I might vote or accept them.

Comment: @GregB I don't know about *"pythonic"* specifically, and I don't have any references to hand, but using class methods as alternate constructors (e.g. `from_string`) is pretty common in Python and keeping a class's responsibilities well defined and self-contained is fundamental to OOP.

Comment: And the list comprehension, as @PauloScardine suggests, is definitely the Pythonic alternative to creating an empty list then repeatedly `append`ing to it - you can use that in tandem with my suggestion, as I've shown below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's part of the job of the `B` class to determine how an instance of some arbitrary other class should be transformed to an instance of `B`, so I would use the *class method* alternate constructor approach, e.g. as follows:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'A({0.name!r}, {0.age!r})'.format(self)


class B(A):

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'B({0.name!r}, {0.age!r})'.format(self)

    @classmethod
    def from_A(cls, inst):
        return cls(inst.name, inst.age)
```

You can then use a simple list comprehension or even `map` to convert a list of one class to another, e.g.:

```
>>> l = [A('Greg', 33), A('John', 39)]
>>> l
[A('Greg', 33), A('John', 39)]

>>> map(B.from_A, l)  # will look different, but is more memory-efficient, in 3.x
[B('Greg', 33), B('John', 39)]

>>> [B.from_A(a) for a in l]  # works (nearly) identically in 2.x and 3.x
[B('Greg', 33), B('John', 39)]
```

Comment: Ok, I like it so far and from what I've read about Pythonicness it seems pretty Pythonic. I'll give it a while to see if there are any other takers but so far you're winning.

Answer (score 1):

Writing data-only objects is frowned upon not only in Python but in most OO-based languages. Probably the most Pythonic way would be pass flat data around, lets say, a dict or list of dicts:

```
{'Greg': 33, 'John': 39}

[{'name': 'Greg', 'age': 33}, {'name': 'John', 'age': 39}]
```

That said, suppose you have classes A and B and you want to instantiate new Bs from existing A instances:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{cls} name={s.name}, age={s.age}>'.format(
            cls=self.__class__.__name__,
            s=self
        )

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, age, born_as='male'):
        super(B, self).__init__(name, age)
        self.born_as = born_as

data = {'Greg': 33, 'John': 39}
list_of_a = [A(k, v) for k, v in data.items()]
```

You can keep it simple and just be explicit:

```
>>> list_of_a
[<A name=Greg, age=33>, <A name=John, age=39>]

>>> [B(a.name, a.age) for a in list_of_a]
[<B name=Greg, age=33>, <B name=John, age=39>]
```

If there are a lot of attributes involved, this can get a bit verbose. Lets teach B how to clone an A:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, age, born_as='male'):
        super(B, self).__init__(name, age)
        self.born_as = born_as

    @classmethod
    def clone(cls, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        return cls(instance.name, instance.age, *args, **kwargs)
```

Since B now knows how to clone A:

```
>>> [B.clone(a) for a in list_of_a]
[<B name=Greg, age=33>, <B name=John, age=39>]
```

It can get tedious to write clone methods for all B-like classes. Introspection is very Pythonic, so lets not repeat ourselves:

```
class CloneFromInstanceMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def clone(cls, instance, **kwargs):
        constructor_args = inspect.getargspec(instance.__init__).args
        for attr_name in constructor_args:
            if attr_name in kwargs:
                continue # overrides instance attribute
            try:
                kwargs[attr_name] = getattr(instance, attr_name)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        return cls(**kwargs)

class B(CloneFromInstanceMixin, A):
    def __init__(self, name, age, born_as='male'):
        super(B, self).__init__(name, age)
        self.born_as = born_as

>>> [B.clone(a) for a in list_of_a]
[<B name=Greg, age=33>, <B name=John, age=39>]
```

I probably have too much free time.

Comment: I disagree with your first point regarding data-only objects. Are you familiar with the [Primitive Obsession](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrimitiveObsession) smell?

Comment: May be you are right, but in a dynamic language like Python I don't see the point of defining classes if you are not intending to couple some methods with data. A counterpoint: http://blog.activelylazy.co.uk/2015/09/25/your-di-framework-is-killing-your-code/

Comment: BTW, the solution proposed in the "Primitive Obsession smell" explicitly encourages you to couple methods with data, see their point about "attractive code".

Comment: Sure, it's worth noting my types `A` and `B` are contrived and purely for the purposes of my example code. Thanks for the mixin example. Interesting to see that way of working.